# MQTT JSON format for IoMT industry?

Tags: protocols, standards

W.r.t. formatting the payload content of MQTT messages one usually sticks to standards like SensorML for distributed sensor networks or Sparkplug for IIoT. Are there JSON format schemas/standards for the Internet of Medical Things domain as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MQTT JSON format for process automation industry?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/5363/mqtt-json-format-for-process-automation-industry)

Comment: I've never been involved in an IoMT project yet. I'm not sure if the industrial domain meta data is the proper one for IoMT scenarios as well.

Comment: The Sparkplug specification states that it has been developed specifically for SCADA/IIoT use cases. However it is suitable for SmartCity use cases as well.